# Необходимость запятой в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложении "Помоги ребенку сегодня и ты изменишь его завтра"?
Если не нужна, то почему (какое правило пунктуации здесь работает?)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

***ЗАПЯТУЮ можно поставить, так как это сложносочинённое предложение. Но в вашем случае запятую лучше заменить на ТИРЕ.***

В некоторых случаях в сложносочинённом предложении перед союзом «и» не ставится запятая. Если же во второй части сложного предложения сообщается о резкой смене событий, а также имеется неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление, то между простыми предложениями ставится пунктуационный знак **тире**. Раздался шелест веток — и передо мной выскочил пёс Дружок. Я бегу туда со всех ног — а там уже все собрались. [Тире в сложносочинённом предложении](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/tire-slozhnosochinennom-predlozhenii-primeryi.html)

Answer (score 1):

Тут лучше поставить тире, так как тут выражаются последствия (следственная связь):

`Помоги ребенку сегодня - и ты изменишь его завтра.`

Народный пример:

`Сделал дело - гуляй смело.`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/29681)

Comment: @behemothus Что не так? С чем вы не согласны?